# how to find out if I can use HP secure encryption

Tags: encryption, redhat-enterprise-linux, hp-proliant

I have a server that does not have an order sheet of what all was included when the server was bought. I would like to try and implement HP Secure Encryption ([link](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04122008&DocLang=en&docLocale=en_US&jumpid=reg_r1002_usen_c-001_title_r0002)) but am not sure if I have all the core components on a **HP DL380** is there any way to list to see if it has the correct hardware on **RHEL 6.6**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the HAL command `lshal` to get a list of all the hardware. You might need to install it and its dependencies first.

```
yum -y install hal dbus
service messagebus start
service haldaemon start
lshal
```

There will be a lot of stuff listed. From that list, you should be able figure out if you have the correct hardware.